# apply function depending on columns value

Tags: r, if-statement, apply

I would like first to mean columns of a given dataframe, if the elements to be meaned satisfy a given condition (Age <18 years). To make things clear, what I want to do is to get a column which is the mean age of children under 18 years old, otherwise report a 0. I tried the following codes :

```
df <- dataframe (A1 = c("58"; "51", "5", "88", "16", "24"), 
                  A2 = c ("75", "57", "44", "2", "81", "4"),
                  A3 = c ("1" ,"51", "65", "54", "88", "12"),
                  A4 = c ("24" ,"8", "81", "32", "5", "86"),
                  D1 = c("1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0"),
                  D2 = c ("0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0"),
                  D3 = c ("1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0"),
                  D4 = c ("1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0"))

df$X_mean <- apply(df[, c ("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4")],
                                   1, function(x) mean (which(x<18)))
```

I tried also :

```
my.fun<-function(x,y){
  if(x<18){
    mean}
}

df$X_mean<-apply(df,MAR=1,FUN=my.fun,x=df[, c ("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4")] )
```

Or,

```
df[, c ("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4")] %>%  mutate_if(x<18, mean)
```

All of these lines didn't work.

Also, I would like to create 4 columns (Cond_Di), depending on both specific columns Ai and Di (i=1 to 4)

if Ai < 18 and Di == 1 so Cond_Di = 1 otherwise 0. And make it for all the Ai and respective Di. That's to say : A1 and D1 ==> Cond_D1 , A2 and D2 ==> Cond_D2 etc.

To summarize, I'd like to create one column that is the mean of values under 18 and four other columns that is 1 = disease for individual under 18 and O = Otherwise
So the outputs would be :

```
> df
  A1 A2 A3 A4 D1 D2 D3 D4 mean_under_18 cond_D1 cond_D2 cond_D3 cond_D4
1 58 75  1 24  1  0  1  1           1.0       0       0       1       0
2 51 12 51  8  0  0  0  1          10.0       0       0       0       1
3  5 44 65 81  0  0  1  1           5.0       0       0       0       0
4 88  2 15 32  1  1  1  0          13.5       0       1       1       0
5 16 81 88  5  0  1  0  0          10.5       0       0       0       0
6 24  4 12 86  0  1  0  0           8.0       0       1       0       0
```

Comment: Yes it is in R language

Comment: Do you want the mean of a column if that mean is <18, or do you want the mean if any age/number in the column is <18?

Comment: Thank you. I'd like the mean of the columns where any age is <18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code (please not that the first data.frame you defined is different with the one you specified as the desired result, I used the first one in the following code)

```
df<- data.frame(A1 = c(58, 51, 5, 88, 16, 24), 
                A2 = c(75, 57, 44, 2, 81, 4),
                A3 = c(1, 51, 65, 54, 88, 12),
                A4 = c(24, 8, 81, 32, 5, 86),
                D1 = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
                D2 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0),
                D3 = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0),
                D4 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))

df$mean_under_18 <- apply(df[, paste0("A", 1:4)], 1, function(x) {
  under_18 <- x < 18
  ifelse(any(under_18), mean(x[under_18]), 0)
})

for (i in 1:4) {
  # Get cols A and D
  col_A <- df[, paste0("A", i)]
  col_D <- df[, paste0("D", i)]
  
  # Mask for under 18 observations
  under_18 <- col_A < 18
  
  # Create cond_D column
  df[[paste0("cond_D", i)]] <- as.integer(under_18 & col_D)
}
```

The resulting data.frame:

```
> df
  A1 A2 A3 A4 D1 D2 D3 D4 mean_under_18 cond_D1 cond_D2 cond_D3 cond_D4
1 58 75  1 24  1  0  1  1           1.0       0       0       1       0
2 51 57 51  8  0  0  0  1           8.0       0       0       0       1
3  5 44 65 81  0  0  1  1           5.0       0       0       0       0
4 88  2 54 32  1  1  1  0           2.0       0       1       0       0
5 16 81 88  5  0  1  0  0          10.5       0       0       0       0
6 24  4 12 86  0  0  0  0           8.0       0       0       0       0
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry for being not clear enough, I tried to, it's not my field. It is perfect for the cond_D1 to D4. However, for the mean, it is not exactly what I would like. I have edited my question with the outputs I'd like to see and clarified it.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is what you want, but I think its getting there. About your follow up question; could you produce an example output which you would like to see?

```
rm(list = ls())
df <- data.frame (A1 = c (58, 51, 5,  88, 16, 24), 
                  A2 = c (75, 57, 44, 2 , 81, 4),
                  A3 = c (1 , 51, 65, 54, 88, 12),
                  A4 = c (24, 8 , 81, 32, 5 , 86),
                  D1 = c (1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0),
                  D2 = c (0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0),
                  D3 = c (1 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0),
                  D4 = c (1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0))

returnval <- numeric(ncol(df))
count <- 1
for (i in colnames(df)){
  for (j in 1:length(df[[i]])){
    if (df[[i]][j] < 18){
      returnval[count] <- mean(df[[i]])
      count = count + 1
      break
    }
  }
}
returnval
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry, I have edited my question with the outputs I'd like to see and clarified it.